# Is there a program that executes correctly as a parallel program but not as a sequential program?

Tags: c, openmp, specifications

This question is out of plain curiosity.

The OpenMP spec says the following in the "Execution Model" section:

```
"... it is possible and permitted to develop a program that executes correctly
as a parallel program but not as a sequential program ..."
```

So what is an example of such a program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenMP introduces additional semantics that are not present in the underlying serial language. Consider the OpenMP sections as an obvious example. In a serial program sections are simply consecutive blocks of code that execute in a strongly predetermined way: from the first one to the last one. With OpenMP all sections could execute in parallel if there are enough threads to handle them. This could lead to causalities that are simply not possible in the sequential case - for example a later code block cannot influence the execution of a previous one when the program runs sequentially.

Highly artificial example:

```
int flag = 0;

#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        while (!flag) {}
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

This code executes perfectly well with 2 or more OpenMP threads and falls into an endless loop when compiled as serial or if run with `OMP_NUM_THREADS` set to 1. If both sections do not run in parallel, the `while` loop never ends since setting `flag` to true happens after the loop in the sequential code.

Answer (score 0):

The sequential model simply stubs out OpenMP calls.  This means that certain actions will not be taken even though the code may look like it would be.

This is not to say there is no algorithm which could possibly solve the problem sequentially -- simply that some programs, AS WRITTEN, may not come to the correct answer without the normal OpenMP calls working in parallel mode.

Comment: I understand that and would like to see an example of such a program.

Comment: @zr. This is highly contrived, but if the program had to complete in 10 seconds, but in sequential mode, because it could not make use of additional resources, it would require 20 seconds to complete.  If it actually had a timer in the program that exited after 10 seconds if the answer hadn't been computed, that program would fail in sequential mode but not in parallel.